# Expressjs File Upload Customization

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

Expressjs has bodyParser middleware which can handle file-uploads and can even store them in a directory given in options. But in my app I want to store the files in Amazon S3, so I basically want to stream the file straight to S3 without having to store it locally at all.

*But the problem is validation of the file*. How can I be sure that these files are all images. Checking the content-type isn't good enough option coz that can be faked. **I want to know is it ok if I do the validation after streaming the file to S3??** I am asking from the security point of view.

**After storing the image, I need to retrieve it for creating thumbnails, How can I do it asynchronously after giving the response after file upload?**

Answer (score 0):

You have contradictory goals of not wanting to store it locally during upload but then also wanting to download it needlessly again to make thumbnails. If you want to go for technical slickness awards, you can simultaneously stream the file upload request body to a local temporary file as well as S3. Or you can do what the rest of the industry does and store it in a local temporary file and then thumbnail it, and then upload all sizes to S3. Either of these approaches alleviates any need to immediately download it from S3 to make thumbnails.

How exactly do you intend to validate that it's really an image? You could look at the first chunk of file data and validate for [the file type's magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) if that gives you warm fuzzies, but ultimately it's untrusted user data. The second half of the supposed image file could be virus code and that is just as easily faked at the `Content-Type` header. Sounds like your security concerns are mostly driven by [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) as opposed to specific threats you intend to defend against. As long as you don't take the user's uploaded data, mark it executable and run it as root on your server, any non-image data is just going to be corrupt and fail to render correctly in a browser (and/or cause your thumbnailer program to exit with an error or perhaps crash in an extreme case).

> Regarding validation can I just try to create a thumbnail and if I can't then its not a valid image and delete it. Is this way fine?

Most of the time, yes. There will be edge cases where your thumbnailer cannot process an image but a browser can as thumbnailers are not perfect and some images are partially corrupt. For example, I have found some animated GIFs that render and animate fine in a web browser but graphicsmagick crashes trying to process them. Not sure there's anything that can be done about those 0.01% edge cases.

> And for uploads part, can I send a response to the user and than carry on with the thumbnail creation and storing it in S3?

Yes, that is generally the best approach so the user knows their upload succeeded. Generally image processing is usually architected as a "work queue" model where you just record that there's work to do and then proceed and a separate process or processes take work off the queue and complete it.

Comment: Regarding validation can I just try to create a thumbnail and if I can't then its not a valid image and delete it. Is this way fine?

Comment: And for uploads part, can I send a response to the user and than carry on with the thumbnail creation and storing it in S3?